# How do you shift in a 2D image in java?

Tags: java, arrays, image, multidimensional-array, shift

Calling shift finds an image which is hidden in the image data, by saving bit 7, shifting bits 0-6 one position to the left, and setting bit 0 to the previously saved value of bit 7.

what does that mean??

```
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                int pixel = image[row][col];
                pixel = (pixel & 0b01111111) << 1;
                image[row][col] = pixel;
```

this is what I have so far, it shifts, however I am not sure how to put the bit 0 to the previously saved value of bit 7.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 7 bits: 1001110
First you save bit 7: 1
Then shift bits 0-6 left: 0011100
Set bit 0 to the saved bit 7: 0011101

If you compare the input and output, you're effectively shifting the whole set of bits left (including wrap-around).

I'm not sure about the specifics of the problem, but think of your bits as pixels. 0 means there isn't a pixel there, 1 means there is. By shifting the bits (representation of the image), you also shift the image.

1001110 // bit data
.  ...  // let's say this is your image
  ... . // shifted image

Sample code:

```
byte[] arr = {0,1,0,1,1,0,1};
byte temp = arr[0];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
arr[i] = temp;
```

Edit:

Based on your example, if you want to set the 0th bit to the previous 8th bit, you can do:

```
int temp = (pixel&(1<<8))>>8;
pixel = (pixel & 0b011111111) << 1;
if (temp==1) pixel |= 0b000000001;
```

Comment: i have this
for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
             for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                 int pixel = image[row][col];
                 pixel = (pixel & 0b01111111) << 1;
                 image[row][col] = pixel;

but im not sure how to put the saved 7 bit back into the new bit.... @Pushkin

Comment: Could you post your code as an edit to your question? It's difficult to read if it's not formatted. Also is each row 7 or 8 bits? Thanks.
Edit: Wait I think I misunderstood it. Each pixel has 8 bits and you have width x height pixels, right?

Comment: OK done, and i believe 8? so only 8 bits are valid for each pixel. These are numbered bits 0-7.

Comment: And what do the bits of each pixel represent exactly, color?
I think I didn't totally answer your question then, since I thought you meant that each bit represented a pixel.

Comment: no not color, the pixel of where it that part of the picture is currently placed at.. if that makes sense.

Comment: ehh, I'm not totally clear what the means, but I'll see if I can fix your issue.

Comment: ok, Im sorry, my english is not so good so i do not know how to explain it better.

Comment: no worries :)
So you have 8 bits and you only want to shift the last 7?
input: 01010101
do you want the output to be: 10101010 or 00101011 (do you want to change the sign bit or not?)

Comment: The first one, no sign bit. when it run, it says this 10001110 (this is just example) but it should be 10001111.